# In a Bayesian network, does the removal of an edge ever remove existing conditional independences?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network, causal-diagrams

I am wondering if the removal of any edge in a acyclic Bayesian network ever removes an existing conditional independence?

Intuitively, I would think not, but I was wondering if there is a formal proof for this?

For example:

```
A -> B -> C
```

Then we have $A \perp C | B$, but if we remove any of the edges, we would still have $A \perp C | B$.

Comment: Have you seen how conditional independence statements are derived from the factorized probability function that comes from the [definition of a graphical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#Definitions_and_concepts)? I suggest working this out on your example graphs.

Comment: Yes I have seen that. I guess is the intuition that removing edges removes `x_pa`, so therefore it can only ever increase the number of conditional independences?

Comment: Something like that sounds right. I think it's worth working it out in more detail.